# Escape keywords in DB name in spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a database named `serde_dwh`

I am trying to access one of its table using Spark SQL.

```scala
val record_count = spark.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM serde_dwh.tableA")
```

Since the database name starts with `serd`, I am receiving below error:

> ERROR Table: Unable to get field from serde:
> `org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe`

I tried with:

```scala
val record_count = spark.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `serde_dwh.tableA`")
```

But I Received:

> NoSuchTableException: Table or view error

The database and the table are available. How to escape `serde` in database name in Spark SQL?

Answer (score 0):

The back-quotes should go around each identifier like this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `serde_dwh`.`tableA`
```

Comment: I tried. val record_count = spark.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `serde_dwh`.`tableA`"), still not working. received ERROR Table: Unable to get field from serde: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe